# Open Firebase Database Feed

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

does anyone have a suggestion how to get rid off the user obligation when posting new element to the Firebase database? I would like to create open feed but this is only for one particular user.
Thank you!

The function starts like:

```
   func fetchPosts(){

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot inlet users = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
```

The main problem I see in this:

```
        for (_,value) in users {
            if let uid = value["uid"] as? String {
                if uid == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                    if let followingUsers = value["following"] as? [String : String]{
                        for (_,user) in followingUsers{
                            self.following.append(user)
                        }
                    }
                    self.following.append(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)

                    ref.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in


                        let postsSnap = snap.value as! [String : AnyObject]

                        for (_,post) in postsSnap {
                            if let userID = post["userID"] as? String {
                                for each in self.following {
                                    if each == userID {
```

I guess this would be the same:

```
                                        let posst = Post()
                                        if let author = post["author"] as? String, let likes = post["likes"] as? Int, let pathToImage = post["pathToImage"] as? String, let postID = post["postID"] as? String {

                                            posst.author = author
                                            posst.likes = likes
                                            posst.pathToImage = pathToImage
                                            posst.postID = postID
                                            posst.userID = userID
                                            if let people = post["peopleWhoLike"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                                                for (_,person) in people {
                                                    posst.peopleWhoLike.append(person as! String)
                                                }
                                            }

                                            self.posts.append(posst)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                self.collectionview.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }

    })}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking; are you stating you want anybody to be able to access your Firebase? If so, then set read and write rules to true and you're good to go. It's also not clear what *main problem* you are finding in your code. If you can clarify your question, we'll take a look.

Comment: This code is originally taken from this video: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fw7ySRFtX_M&t=1920s). Author is creating Instagram like app and to display the feed, he is using the code written above. I would like to use the same sample but with the feed open to everyone. In other words, the code above should be some how remade to create feed which is not related to the User UID and also the Auth function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so if I am understanding your question correctly you want anyone signed in to be able to see all the posts not just the posts of the users they are following.

If this is in fact the case then you do not need to check who the user is following. You just want to load all of the posts. Change

```
for (_,post) in postsSnap {
     if let userID = post["userID"] as? String {
          for each in self.following {
               if each == userID {
```

To

```
  self.ref.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in
                        if let postsSnap = snap.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                            for(_, post) in postsSnap {
                                if let userID = post["userID"] as? String {
                                    for each in self.following {
                                        if each == userID {
                                            let posst = Post()

                                            if let author = post["author"] as? String, let likes = post["likes"] as? Int, let pathToImage = post["pathToImage"] as? String, let postID = post["postID"] as? String, let postDescription = post["postDescription"] as? String, let timestamp = post["timestamp"] as? Double, let category = post["category"] as? String, let group = post["group"] as? Int {

                                                posst.author = author
                                                posst.likes = likes
                                                posst.pathToImage = pathToImage
                                                posst.postID = postID
                                                posst.userID = userID
                                                posst.fancyPostDescription = self.createAttributedString(author: author, postText: postDescription)
                                                posst.postDescription = author + ": " + postDescription
                                                posst.timestamp = timestamp
                                                posst.group = group
                                                posst.category = category
                                                posst.userWhoPostedLabel = self.createAttributedPostLabel(username: author, table: group, category: category)

                                                if let people = post["peopleWhoLike"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                                                    for(_, person) in people {
                                                        posst.peopleWhoLike.append(person as! String)
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                self.posts.append(posst)
                                            } // end if let
                                        }
                                    }
                                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    ref.removeAllObservers()
```

If you want anyone to be able to read / write to your database you have to update the rules in the Firebase console. You do this by clicking on database then rules. The default rules look like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Change them to

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

I looked at the video you're following and he make's a lot of mistakes. Really when you request data from Firebase you should be paging i.e. loading a set number of posts and then loading more based on the scroll position.

Comment: I am so sorry but this code still includes the UserID. After deleting the first 4 lines of code, it still shows warnings.

Comment: Sorry for being annoying but nowhere is written how to read data from Firebase without logged in user and also, using UIViewController with Tableview.

Comment: I'm just saving the userID in the post object I'm not using it to filter out posts like you were in your code. If you want a user to be able to read/write to the database without being authenticated you have to change the database rules. I'll update my post.

Comment: now I understand. For open database, the reading rule must be for anyone. Therefore, ".read": "true". Thanks!